# Dropbox file upload puts user over quota?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

Does anyone know if `[restClient uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:sourcePath];` will trigger `- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error` with `error.code == 507` (507 == User over Quota) if you try to upload a file with a size greater than the available space?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Simply stash a bunch of random crap in your box until it is full, then try uploading more using the API and tell us if that did what you hoped for.